# NetBeans conditional breakpoint not working

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a conditional break point set within a long loop.  Here it is:

```
maBuyPeriod==55 && maSellPeriod==65 && quote.Symbol.equals("VAW")
```

Suspend is set to "Breakpoint thread".
In debugging mode, I can step over, step into, etc just fine.  But when I click the Continue button, the debugging suspends on the current line without proceeding to the breakpoint.

This is NetBeans IDE 10.0.  I have never been successful at getting conditional breakpoints to work.  Suggestions?

Comment: Stupid question: are you sure that this condition is really ever met? Is quote.Symbol really uppercase? Have you tried equalsIgnoreCase? Are you sure the line you set your breakpoint on is really executed (check with an unconditional breakpoint)? What do you mean by "debugging suspends on the current line"? Does the program does not get executed any further?

Comment: Yes, correct. The program does not get executed any further.